# How to represent sub-documents in JSON array as Java Collection using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I would appreciate any help to know the best way to deserialize the following JSON response which we receive from Salesforce into a Java object using Jackson Annotations.

```
"records": [
  {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "Lead",
        "url": "/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Lead/00Qi000000Jr44XEAR"
      },
      "Id": "00Qi000000Jr44XEAR",
      "Name": "Kristen Akin",
      "Address": {
          "city": null,
          "country": "USA",
          "state": "CA",
          "stateCode": null,
          "street": null
      },
      "Phone": "(434) 369-3100",
  },
  {
      "attributes": {
      "type": "Lead",
      "url": "/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Lead/00Qi000000Jugv2EAB"
      },
      "Id": "00Qi000000Jugv2EAB",
      "Name": "Sarah Jones",
      "Address": {
        "city": null,
        "country": null,
        "state": "CA",
        "stateCode": null,
        "street": null
      },
      "Phone": "(408) 338-6066",
  }
]}
```

The above JSON response is an array which contains 2 elements. I would like to represent this JSON structure as a Java Collection using Jackson, something like:

```
@JsonProperty("records")
ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<?, ?>> recordList
```

The above object representation deserializes the JSON response and represent as a Key-Value pair in HashMap but issue is representing "attributes" and "Address" subdocuments. In the above HashMap their value is being represented as the respective JSON subdocument whereas I would prefer to have Attributes subdocument gets mapped to an Attribute object and similarly Address subdocument mapped to an Address object in the HashMap, something like:

```
Key            Value
attributes     <Attributes> object
Id             00Qi000000Jr44XEAR
.....
Address        <Address> object
Phone          (434) 369-3100
```

After doing some Google search, I figured I might have to use @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes attributes as mentioned in this [link](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.in/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html).

However, I could not figure how to use these annotations in this specific scenario. Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: what is the type of Key and Value in your `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: Key as String and Value as Object

Comment: Are `Attributes` and `Address` your custom classes?

Comment: Yes, `Attributes` and `Address` are my custom classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the structure of your JSON input is completely dynamic, you can read it as JsonNode or even as Map. Refer to this [link](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel) for more info.

If you want to map your JSON to java classes but you don't know all the attributes in compile type,  you can leverage [the @JsonAnyGetter/@JsonAnySetter annotations](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html). Here is an example based on your JSON that stores the unknown attributes for the Address class in the internal map.

```
public class JacksonMapping {
    public static final String JSON = "...";

    public static class Attributes {
        public String type;
        public URI url;
    }

    public static class Address {
        public String city;
        public String country;
        public String state;
        public Integer stateCode;
        public String street;
        private final Map<String, Object> otherAttributes = new HashMap<>();

        @JsonAnySetter
        public void setProperty(String name, Object value) {
            otherAttributes.put(name, value);
        }

        @JsonAnyGetter
        public Map<String, Object> getOtherAttributes() {
            return otherAttributes;
        }
    }

    public static class Record {
        @JsonProperty("Id")
        public String id;
        @JsonProperty("Name")
        public String name;
        public Attributes attributes;
        @JsonProperty("Address")
        public Address address;
        @JsonProperty("Phone")
        public String phone;
    }

    public static class RecordList {
        public List<Record> records;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        RecordList recordList = mapper.readValue(JSON, RecordList.class);
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(recordList));
    }

}
```

I can also try to generate java objects from your JSON with a help from a tool. For example this one: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Comment: Thanks Alexey for your response. The solution you suggested would work if fields we receive from Salesforce is static. For simplicity I have just posted basic fields but in reality they will be more and it may change from customer to customer as Salesforce offers lot of customization. Hence I would like to avoid creating specific fields in class, as if we have a customer with some new fields then I have to change the class structure. That is why I want to add them into HashMap<String, Object> where Attributes and Address sub-documents get mapped to the respective custom object. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. This is what I was looking for. I have accepted your answer.